# Valgrind показывает потери памяти при проверке qt программы

Tags: linux, qt, память, valgrind

Имеется простейшая программа на с++:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  ::QApplication app(argc, argv);
  ::QWidget wgt;

  wgt.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

При проверке ее с помощью `valgrind` он выдает вот это:

```
==4179== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4179== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4179== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4179== Command: ./qt -style Fusion
==4179== 
==4179== 
==4179== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4179==     in use at exit: 1,364,611 bytes in 13,262 blocks
==4179==   total heap usage: 134,843 allocs, 121,581 frees, 84,547,146 bytes allocated
==4179== 
==4179== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4179==    definitely lost: 540 bytes in 4 blocks
==4179==    indirectly lost: 12,986 bytes in 78 blocks
==4179==      possibly lost: 3,200 bytes in 26 blocks
==4179==    still reachable: 1,285,749 bytes in 12,645 blocks 
==4179==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==4179==                         length64           : 3,272 bytes in 59 blocks
==4179==                         newarray           : 2,096 bytes in 51 blocks
==4179==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4179== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==4179== 
==4179== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4179== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

в чем дело?